# Passing functions into other components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm working on cleaning up the code in my first project by breaking some of the components down into smaller pieces, but I am struggling to find the best practice on passing a function from one component to another. There is also the possibility I am just going about this all wrong! Any advice is appreciated. Below is the code for a function I'd like to be able to use in multiple components `ScryfallQuery`, in this specific instance I am trying to pass it into the `FileHandler` component which is currently rendering the following error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'ScryfallQuery')
    at fileHandler.js:50:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at updateCards (fileHandler.js:43:1)
    at fileHandler.js:67:1
    at invokePassiveEffectCreate (react-dom.development.js:23487:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:23574:1)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
```

If anyone could point me to the correct literature that would also be helpful. The react documentation here https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html doesn't seem to have correct way to pass functions with the syntax I have at hand (maybe thats the problem?). I'm still learning React (and js!) so there maybe something obvious here I am missing.

But to reiterate, I'm looking for the best way to pass a function, in this case, my API query into multiple components.

Here is my App.js code:

```
    import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'
    import './styles/App.css';
    import FileHandler from './Components/fileHandler';
    import ImagePreviewer from './Components/ImagePreviewer';
    import { Header } from './Components/Header';
    import { Comparison } from './Components/Comparison';
    import {ScryfallQuery} from './Components/ScryfallQuery';
    
function App() {
          const [cardInput, setCardInput] = useState([]);
          const [cards, setCards] = useState([]);
          const [previewCard, setPreviewCard] = useState([]);
          const [comparisonCard, setComparisonCard] = useState([]);
        
          return (
            <div className="container"> 
              {/* <GlobalState> */}
                <Header />
                {cards && <Comparison comparison={comparisonCard} setComparisonCard={setComparisonCard}/>}
                <div className="row" id="table-main">
                  <div className="col-3">
                    <ImagePreviewer previewCard={previewCard} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-9">
                    <FileHandler 
                      cardInput={cardInput}
                      setCardInput={setCardInput}
                      
                      previewCard={previewCard} 
                      setPreviewCard={setPreviewCard}
        
                      cards={cards}
                      setCards={setCards}
        
                      scryfallQuery={ScryfallQuery}
                      
                    />
                  </div>
                </div>
              {/*</GlobalState> */}
              </div>    
          );
        }
        
        export default App;
```

Here is the code for the component holding the function:

```
export const ScryfallQuery = () => {
     
    /*collection query function for more info read 
    here: https://scryfall.com/docs/api/cards */ 
    
    const queryString = `https://api.scryfall.com/cards/collection`;
    const queryStringified = JSON.stringify(query);
    
    return fetch(queryString, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: queryStringified
    }).then((res, err) => {
        if (res) return res.json();
        if (err) return new Error("Error: ", err);
    });
    
    /* scryfall api accepts maximum 75 card query, 
    batches query in 75 increments */

    function sliceIntoBatches(arr, batchSize) {;
        const batchArr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
            const batch = arr.slice(i, i + batchSize);
            batchArr.push(batch);
        }
        return batchArr;
    };
}
```

and lastly here is the code for the file I am passing the function into:

```
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import { Card } from './Card.js';

export const FileHandler = ({
  cardInput, setCardInput, 
  cards, setCards, 
  previewCard, setPreviewCard,
  ScryfallQuery
}) => {

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', function(){
      const allCards = this.result.split(/\r?\n/g);
      setCardInput(allCards)   
  });


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    /* scryfall api accepts maximum 75 card query, 
    batches query in 75 increments */
    function sliceIntoBatches(arr, batchSize) {;
        const batchArr = []
        for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += batchSize) {
            const batch = arr.slice(i, i + batchSize);
            batchArr.push(batch);
        }
        return batchArr;
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    const parseInput = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      setCardInput([]);
      reader.readAsText(document.getElementById('input').files[0])
    }

    const updateCards = () => {
      let response;

      const cardBatches = sliceIntoBatches(cardInput, 75);

      cardBatches.forEach(async (cardBatch) => {
        const queryArray = cardBatch.filter(cardName => cardName !== '').map(cardName => {
          return {
            name: cardName
          }
        }); 

        response = await this.ScryfallQuery({ identifiers: queryArray });

        if (response) {
          console.log("response", response);
          if (response.data.length > 0) {
            console.log("second check", cards)
            const newCards = [...cards, ...response.data];
            setCards(newCards);
          } else if (response.not_found.length > 0 || response.data.length <= 0) {
            console.error("Cards not found: ", response.not_found);
          }}
      });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log("loading");
      if (cardInput.length > 0 && cards.length === 0) {
        updateCards();
      }
    }, [cardInput]);


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    function scryfallCollectionQuery(query) {
        const queryString = `https://api.scryfall.com/cards/collection`;
        const queryStringified = JSON.stringify(query);
      
        return fetch(queryString, {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          },
          body: queryStringified
        }).then((res, err) => {
          if (res) return res.json();
          if (err) return new Error("Error: ", err);
        });
      }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////      
    return(
         <div className="App">
            <h1>Submit a .txt file of cards! </h1>
            <form target="_self" onSubmit={parseInput}>
                <input type="file" id="input" />
                <button id="submit">Submit</button>
                <pre id="preReader"></pre>
            </form>
            
           {cards &&
              <table id="table-head">
                <tbody>  
                  <tr>
                    <td id="card-number-title">#</td>
                    <td id="card-name-title">Card Name</td>
                    <td id="card-data-title">Colors</td>
                    <td id="card-data-title">Rarity</td>
                    <td id="card-data-title">ELO</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table> } 
          {cards && cards.map(card => 
            <Card
              card={card} 
              setPreviewCard={setPreviewCard} />
            )} 
        </div>   
    )
}

export default FileHandler;
```

Answer (score 1):

You pass the reference to the function as `scryfallQuery` prop (with lowercase `s`).

```
<FileHandler 
  cardInput={cardInput}
  setCardInput={setCardInput}
  previewCard={previewCard} 
  setPreviewCard={setPreviewCard}
  cards={cards}
  setCards={setCards}
  scryfallQuery={ScryfallQuery}
/>
```

Then inside `FileHandler` you try to use it with uppercase `S`:

```
export const FileHandler = ({
  cardInput, setCardInput, 
  cards, setCards, 
  previewCard, setPreviewCard,
  ScryfallQuery
})
```

And why exactly are you using `this` here:

```
response = await this.ScryfallQuery({ identifiers: queryArray });
```

I don't know if those are all the mistakes but your code is a mess and it's hard to read. Would be nice to get only the relevant code snippets.

Comment: It is that way because I am bad at this and trying to learn. =)

Fixed the first code example, and am passing with proper capitalization.

the "this." was there as an attempt to try to call the function based on the the documentation in react, but I am really unsure of what I am doing.

I was scolded on my first post for not including my full code, sorry it's a mess I'm trying to clean it up and get better.

Comment: You have to learn the difference between react class based components and functional components. I suggest you check a react guide/tutorial/course, learning this alone will be hard as a lot of documentation is still using the old class based components.

Comment: Thank you for point me in a direction, I understand they are different. In this case, would I want to use a class based component if I am looking to pass a function between them, or are you just referencing this because of the ".this" I had in my code? 

Thank you again!

Comment: No, functional components are preferred, they are easier to write and simpler to read, class based components are a relic of past. What I am trying to say is you don't have to use `this` in this case, functional components don't utilize the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to import `ScryfallQuery` into App.js?

Comment: Great thought, I realize that my imports got caught off in the code snippet, so I updated them here.

Comment: I see. I think it's because you are calling `this.ScryfallQuery` when it should just be `ScryfallQuery`. This is just a normal parameter and not part of the component itself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a function from a parent to children you have to use a prop

Example:

```
const parent = () =>{


const handleconsolelog = () =>{
console.log("hi")
}

return (

<children handleconsolelog={handleconsolelog}
)
}
```

Then in the children:

```
const childeren= ({handleconsolelog}) =>{

return (

<button onClick={handleconsolelog} />


)
}
```

Comment: I saw this example in the react documentation, but I guess I am misunderstanding the implementation, because I believe I have that in my code but it isn't working.

Is the error that I am importing the function to my App file, and it's not hardcoded there?